# Event for closing Android Notification Drawer

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there a way I could get notified when the notification drawer is closed/opened?

Comment: Yes. Show us your code...

Comment: You can Check it by using a boolean like this
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT);

Comment: can I somehow register a receiver for such event?

Comment: Yes. I personally took Google's code at https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and then I implemented my own interface to act as a simple Listener.